# using arcpy to convert labels to annotation

Tags: arcpy, annotation

I am trying to use ArcPy to convert a specific shapefile in my TOC to annotation in the map. I am not so much in the need for the tiled annotation tool that I've seen talked about as this is going to be used at the layout view at the same scale always. Essentially I am trying to label all the areas in the [area] field and then convert to annotation right after so they can be dragged around for best look as there can be sometimes up to 50 different labels.

I've been trying this with no luck

```
def onGenerate(self, event):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'labels generated','success',wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
    layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "project_app")[0] 
    if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in layer.labelClasses:
            lblclass.showClassLabels = True
            arcpy.ConvertLabelsToAnnotation_defense(mxd, layer)
    lblclass.expression = " [NAME]"
    layer.showLabels = True
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: sorry i thought it was in there, i edited it

Comment: do you have the [Defense Mapping Toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/defense-mapping-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-defense-mapping-toolbox.htm)?

Comment: Ah no I do not. Do you know if this is the only way to convert a label to annotation in ArcPy by any chance? Thanks

Comment: None that I'm aware of

Comment: Never tried it myself, still 90% certain that it can be done, because annotation is no more than a polygon. It's enough to create shape and populate remaining fields following some rules.

Comment: @FelixIP I'm surprised by your statement that "annotation is no more than a polygon".  I could not find anything quickly in the documentation, and I may be going off ArcInfo Workstation recollections, but I would have thought annotation features could be anchored to a single point, between two points, along lines or within rectangles (and perhaps other polygons).

Comment: @PolyGeo it is most certainly a polygon, just open attribute table. However all my attempts to build it using arcpy failed. Even when I copy entire row, incl. geometry, it result in invalid shape